# Only one valid testCase, can I save the time to write failing ones? (can I automatically generate them)

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, assertj

Imagine the following situation: There is a legacy application I want to write tests for in order to be able to refactor the (ugly) code.

Now there is a big chunk of code that deals with some constraints. Basically it boils down to this signature:

```
public Boolean isValidRequest(Boolean constraint0, Boolean constraint1, Boolean constraint2, BooleanConstraint3) {
    return constraint0 && constraint1 && constraint2 && constraint3;
}
```

Now what I want to test is exactly that "chaining" (here all constraints are chained with "&&", but I want to make sure this stays like it, e.g. no typo!)

In order to test all combinations I would have to write n² tests where n is the number of constraints. Here it would be 4², hence 16 tests.
I wonder if there is a more easy way. The only valid testcase is:

```
@Test
public void testAllConstraintsFulfilled() {
    assertThat(myObjectToTest.isValidRequest(true, true, true, true)).isTrue();
}
```

While all other combinations should fail. I wonder whether there is a way I don't know about to skip manually writing the other 15 testcases and instead say something like:

```
1) Try all combinations
2) Only (true, true, true, true) should not fail
```

I have mockito, assertj and junit4 available. Any hints, ideas?

Comment: You could go with "Parameterized"which was introduced with JUnit4... Have a look here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways here:

A) you turn to **coverage**; and you keep writing test cases until you hit 100%. You don't need to test all **possible** paths - only the **existing** paths that your program can take!

B) you reverse that approach: instead of writing testcases to hit paths; you use a solution that **generates** tests for you. In other words: you provide *rules*, and that an engine verifies that the code under test matches those rules. [QuickCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck) would be one example of such tooling.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The problem is, for that legacy project I cannot bring in any more dependencies. Thanks still, I learned something ;)

Comment: Hint : for option A you don't need further dependencies.  You only use coverage as tool so you can write a complete test suite. So this doesn't affect your existing setup! Well, actually that would be true for both options. You can use all of that fully 'locally'.